# Bean post processor for Retry annotation

Tags: java, spring, proxy

I have a legacy project with Spring version 3.0 (I can't use Retriable annotation from spring package).
I want to implement Retryable annotation to annotate my methods which execution should be retry on fail.

This is my class:

```
@Component
public final class RetryBpp implements BeanPostProcessor {
    private final ConcurrentMap<String, ClassDefinition> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName) throws BeansException {
        final Class<?> asClass = bean.getClass();
        final Method[] methods = asClass.getMethods();
        final List<Method> collect = Stream.of(methods)
                                           .filter(method -> method.isAnnotationPresent(Repitable.class))
                                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
        if(!collect.isEmpty()){
            this.map.put(beanName,new ClassDefinition(collect,asClass));
        }
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName) throws BeansException {
        final ClassDefinition definition = this.map.get(beanName);
        if(definition != null){
            final Class beanClass = definition.asClass;
            return Proxy.newProxyInstance(beanClass.getClassLoader(), beanClass.getInterfaces(), (proxy, method, args) -> {
                if(definition.isMethodPresent(method)){
                    System.out.println("Present");
                    return this.retry(definition.originalMethod(method),bean,args);
                } else{
                    return method.invoke(bean,args);
                }
            });
        } else{
            return bean;
        }
    }

    private Object retry(final Method method,final Object originalBean,Object[] argc){
        final Repitable repitable = method.getAnnotation(Repitable.class);
        int attempts = repitable.attempts();
        Throwable exc = null;
        while(attempts!=0){
            try{
                return method.invoke(originalBean,argc);
            }catch (final Throwable throwable){
                exc = throwable;
                attempts--;
                this.sleep(repitable.delay(),repitable.timeUnit());
            }
        }
        throw new RuntimeException(exc);
    }

    @SneakyThrows(InterruptedException.class)
    private void sleep(final int time, final TimeUnit timeUnit){
        timeUnit.sleep(time);
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    private static final class ClassDefinition{
        private final List<Method> methods;
        private final Class asClass;
        boolean isMethodPresent(final Method method){
            return this.methods.stream().anyMatch(mthd->mthd.getName().equals(method.getName()));
        }
        Method originalMethod(final Method method){
            return this.methods.stream().filter(mthd->mthd.getName().equals(method.getName())).findFirst().orElseThrow(NullPointerException::new);

        }

    }


}
```

And it work but I want to change two things

1)In retry method I want to keep last exception and throw when `repeateCount = 0` for this I need to declare null ptr to `exc`, but I want all my fields to be final. Is it any possible way to rewrite my code?

2) In ClassDefinition I compare `Method` by name because original `equals` method of `Method class` compare by class, I can't do it because original class replaced by proxy, Is it possible to compare two `Method's` in different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part: one option is to use a `List` of the `Throwables`.  And then throw them something like:

```
final RuntimeException theError = new RuntimeException(list.get(list.size() - 1));
for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
    theError.addSuppressed(list.get(i));
}
throw theError;
```

This also gives the benefit of providing *all* the failures.

For the latter part, this could be complicated and expensive depending on whether there's gonna be generics, var-args, etc. on some of the methods.

Since you're already using spring, you could try a combination of: `AopUtils.getTargetClass` and `AopUtils.getMostSpecificMethod` to get what you want (would need to refactor what you pass to some of the test methods).

Something simple to provide some more (note, not infallible) tests in the vein of what you're already running with though:

```
return methods.stream().anyMatch(mthd -> {
    if (!method.getName().equals(mthd.getName())) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!method.getReturnType().isAssignableFrom(mthd.getReturnType())) {
        return false;
    }
    final Class<?>[] parameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
    if (mthd.getParameterTypes().length != parameterTypes.length) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < parameterTypes.length; i++) {
        if (!parameterTypes[i].equals(mthd.getParameterTypes()[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

I'm sure there are some more checks you can do (`Method.getExceptionTypes()` to confirm they *could* override; `Method.getDeclaringClass()` and work up the tree from there; `Method.getModifiers()` to determine if it *could* be overridden, etc.), but that depends on how safe you need to be.